# How to get/demonstrate asynchronous behavior in JavaScript promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

I [read](https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor/blob/master/presentation/README.md) that

> Promises also ensure order-independence. Separating the producer and
>   consumer, so that they can execute independently, is the crux of
>   asynchronous programming. With a promise, you can give a promise to a
>   consumer before giving a resolver to a producer. They can then produce
>   or consume on their own schedule and the promise synchronizes.

Trying to understand the Order Independence described above, I am writing up some code to hopefully demonstrate this. Basically, I wanted to create two asynchronous promises (based on downloading two images at two different times in `partA()` and `partB()`), and then resolve both using `all`.

```
var axios = require('axios');
function loadImage(imgsrc) {
    return axios.get(imgsrc);
}
function partA() {
    var promise1 = loadImage("http://cn.bing.com/s/a/hp_zh_cn.png");
    var promise2 = setTimeout(partB,20000);
    Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function() {
    console.log("The images are loaded");
    });
};

function partB () {
    return loadImage("http://cn.bing.com/s/a/hpc20.png");
};

partA();
```

Here are my issues and questions are:

1. When executing `partA()` in the last line, I expected that I had to wait 20 seconds to see the success message because of the `var promise2 = setTimeout(partB,20000);` line (I had hoped that the two downloads happens 20 seconds apart from each other, for illustration purposes). Maybe I didn't use `setTimeout` right. But in any case, I got the success message almost *immediately* after I call *partA()* in the `babel-node` REPL. *How do I properly get the delay?*
2. In this example (if correct), how can I interpret the Order Independence in terms of `produce or consume on their own schedule`? Where are the sites of production and consumption?

(This is with babel-node 6.24.1 with `--presets es2015` under Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that setTimeout does not return a Promise. You have to insert a promise which executes a timeout to Promise.all.

```
function partA() {
     var promise1 = loadImage("http://cn.bing.com/s/a/hp_zh_cn.png");
     var promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         setTimeout(() => {
             return resolve(partB);
         }, 20000);
     });
     Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function() {
         console.log("The images are loaded");
     });
 };

 function partB() {
     return loadImage("http://cn.bing.com/s/a/hpc20.png");
 };

 partA();
```

In this case, promise2 is actually a promise, which resolves with partB result, after 20 seconds.

Comment: thanks. I tested your code, and it returns the message in about 4 seconds. It makes a difference but not the 20 s I expected. Also, do you know why my code returns the success message if the second promise isn't created/passed correctly? It is an `Promise.all` and doesn't that require all promises in the array to be fulfilled?

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` does not return a promise.

To see order independence at work consider this example:

```
var promise1, promise2;
promise1 = loadImage("http://cn.bing.com/s/a/hp_zh_cn.png");
promise2 = loadImage("http://cn.bing.com/s/a/hpc20.png");
promise1.then(function () {
    console.log("promise1 finished");
});
promise2.then(function () {
    console.log("promise2 finished");
});
Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function() {
    console.log("both finished");
});
```

The output of this script can be either:

```
promise1 finished
promise2 finished
both finished
```

or

```
promise2 finished
promise1 finished
both finished
```

It just depends on which request completes earlier. If you want a more controlled example consider this:

```
var promise1, promise2;
promise1 = create_timeout_promise(20);
promise2 = create_timeout_promise(10);

function create_timeout_promise(timeout) {
    var promise;
    promise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(resolve, timeout);
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Now the exepcted output is:

```
promise2 finished
promise1 finished
both finished
```

Because promise 2 is going to resolve first.

Comment: +1Thanks for the detailed answer. I was trying hard to separate the producer from the consumer in writing up my test, by putting the `then()` as far away from the `new Promise()` as possible (possibly in code and time). Is that the right understanding of separation? I was trying to understand how they can be *separate and independent*, because in the examples I saw so far, the `.then` call are often right next to the promise creation.